# Phantom Wallet blocking transactions that fail to simulate

Tags: transactions, wallet, phantom, sendtransactionerror

Phantom seems to be completely blocking off transactions that are expected to fail on simulation. This is problematic for when trying to chain transactions where we want users to sign only once, but send transactions one-by-one in specific order rather than all at the same time.

The image below shows up when I try to sign multiple transactions, one of which has an `OrcaSwap` call at the end. Said swap instruction is expected to fail if ran by itself since the source token account isn't populated until after the earlier transactions are successful. The weird thing is, the Phantom screen doesn't happen when running the dApp on `localhost`, but it does when deployed to production.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this, or any possible workarounds?

```
// list of possible relevant libraries, in case it's a version issue

  "dependencies": {
    "@orca-so/sdk": "^1.2.25",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.9.5",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.15.4",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.9.6",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.16.7",
    "@solana/web3.js": "1.43.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?